# How to write an S3 function of Colon operator in r

Tags: r, function, amazon-s3

I want to write an S3 method for Colon operator `::` in R.
The default use is `pkg::name`. I use the following usual method:

```
\`::` <- function (pkg, name) UseMethod("::")

\`::.default` <- function (pkg, name) .Primitive("::")(pkg, name)

\`::.numeric` <-  function(pkg, name)  paste0(pkg, name)
```

However, It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your suggestion has some things going against it right off the bat.

There is no .Primitive("::") function.

Also see how base's `::` escapes the names:

```
    > base::"::"
    function (pkg, name) 
    {
        pkg <- as.character(substitute(pkg))
        name <- as.character(substitute(name))
        getExportedValue(pkg, name)
    }
    <bytecode: 0x55ff3f736db0>
    <environment: namespace:base>
```

Still even if you did that properly, I don't think you can get around the name resolution of the first argument when used like this.

From there you also see that you need to call `getExportedValue`

The nearest I can make it work is calling :: in your setup like this:

```
"base"::dim # for example
```

Why do you need this modified :: method?

Comment: Great thanks for your answer.  I am wonder how to write a function like `::`, because it is not a normal one like dim(), or %>% . It is so strange to create. Thanks